# Indefinite Integral of all even function $= 0$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am wondering what's wrong with the following decent-looking proof:
\begin{align*}
\int x^2 dx &= \int (-u)^2(-du)\quad\text{ Let } x=-u\\
&=-\int u^2 du\\
&=-\int x^2 dx \quad \text{Change of dummy variable} \\
2\int x^2 dx&=0\\
\therefore \quad \int x^2 dx&=0
\end{align*}
Which is obviously wrong as $\int x^2 dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$. But I am not quite sure which part went wrong, great thanks for your help.

Comment: The first equality is wrong.

Comment: You can do change of variable only on definite integral. In this last case you have also to swap the integration's set $\int_a^b...\to \int_b^a ...$

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: @geetha290krm would you please elaborate more on how the first equality is wrong?

Comment: while you are changing variable, you are contradicting your proposal  $x=-u$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a **very** good question, and the underlying problem is the difference between definite and indefinite integrals, and the lack of formality when working with definite integrals. Also, and worth noting, the problem **doesn't** have anything to do with indefinite integrals being defined *up to a constant*.

If you tried to do the same trick with definite integrals, it wouldn't work.

The integral you wrote is defined as
$$
F(x) = \int x^2 dx
$$
which formally means $F(x)$ is a function (defined up to some constant) and $F'(x) = x^2$.

The werid thing here is that the variable $x$  is both inside and outside the integral, which doesn't really make sense with definite integrals, but it does with indefinite.

If you do the change of variables now, you get

$$
\int u^2 du = F(u) = F(-x) = \int (-x)^2 d(-x) = -\int x^2dx = -F(x).
$$
So the only information you gain is $F(u)=F(-x)=-F(x)$.

Variable change does not work with functions. You cannot assume $F(u)=F(x)$ by just changing $u$ with $x$. And this is exactly what is being done by changing "the dummy variable" inside the integral.
You are not actually changing a varibale inside an integral, but rather you are changing the variable of a function.
Therefore, saying $\int a(x)dx = \int a(y)dy$ is wrong, because these are not indefinite integrals, but *functions* in $x$, resp. $y$.

Answer (score 7):

There is a problem in the “Change of dummy variable” step. The symbol $u$ is *not* a dummy variable; it stands for $-x$ (and, yes, $x$ *is* a dummy variable). When you get to $-\int u^2\,\mathrm du$, if $\int u^2\,\mathrm du$ is some function $f$ depending on the variable $u$, then you have obtained $-f(u)$. But now, since $u=-x$, this is equal to $-f(-x)$. So, if $f$ is a primitive of $x^2$, all that this proves is that this primitive an odd function (or to be more precise, the sum of an odd function with a constant; always keep in mind that the expression $\int\varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx$ doesn't stand for a single primitive).

Comment: But aren’t all primitives only differ by some constants?

Comment: Yes, and that is why I wrote “the sum of an odd function with a constant”.

Comment: I have added a new sentence to my answer (the second sentence). I hope that it helps to make things clear.

Comment: Why you said that “all that this proves is that this primitive an odd function (or to be more precise, the sum of an odd function with a constant)”. How can I see that?

Comment: @Tim If $F$ and $G$ are primitives of the same function $f$, then $G=F+C$, for some constant $C$. In this case, you have a certain function $F(x)$ and a function $-F(-X)$ are both primitives of the same function. Therefore, for some constant $C$, $F(x)=-F(-x)+C$. But then $F(x)-\frac C2=-F(-x)+\frac C2$; in other words, $F(x)-\frac C2$ is an odd function. That means that is an odd function plus a constant.

Comment: Thank you very much!I know what you mean now.